# Using OpenCv to detect an image and count some basic color of it

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors, detect

```
import numpy as np
import collections
def getColorList():
    dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

    # black
    lower_black = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    upper_black = np.array([180, 255, 46])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_black)
    color_list.append(upper_black)
    dict['black'] = color_list

    # #gray
    # lower_gray = np.array([0, 0, 46])
    # upper_gray = np.array([180, 43, 220])
    # color_list = []
    # color_list.append(lower_gray)
    # color_list.append(upper_gray)
    # dict['gray']=color_list

    # white
    lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 221])
    upper_white = np.array([180, 30, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_white)
    color_list.append(upper_white)
    dict['white'] = color_list

    #red
    lower_red = np.array([156, 43, 46])
    upper_red = np.array([180, 255, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_red)
    color_list.append(upper_red)
    dict['red']=color_list

    # red
    lower_red = np.array([0, 43, 46])
    upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_red)
    color_list.append(upper_red)
    dict['red2'] = color_list

    #orange
    lower_orange = np.array([11, 43, 46])
    upper_orange = np.array([25, 255, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_orange)
    color_list.append(upper_orange)
    dict['orange'] = color_list

    #yellow
    lower_yellow = np.array([26, 43, 46])
    upper_yellow = np.array([34, 255, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_yellow)
    color_list.append(upper_yellow)
    dict['yellow'] = color_list

    #green
    lower_green = np.array([35, 43, 46])
    upper_green = np.array([77, 255, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_green)
    color_list.append(upper_green)
    dict['green'] = color_list

    #cyan
    lower_cyan = np.array([78, 43, 46])
    upper_cyan = np.array([99, 255, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_cyan)
    color_list.append(upper_cyan)
    dict['cyan'] = color_list

    #blue
    lower_blue = np.array([100, 43, 46])
    upper_blue = np.array([124, 255, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_blue)
    color_list.append(upper_blue)
    dict['blue'] = color_list

    # purple
    lower_purple = np.array([125, 43, 46])
    upper_purple = np.array([155, 255, 255])
    color_list = []
    color_list.append(lower_purple)
    color_list.append(upper_purple)
    dict['purple'] = color_list

    return dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    color_dict = getColorList()
    print(color_dict)

    num = len(color_dict)
    print('num=',num)

    for d in color_dict:
        print('key=',d)
        print('value=',color_dict[d][1])
```

I wanted to put an image in the colorlist which could help me detect the basic color in the other image. So when I put an image which have red and white included it will show me the results.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What is the expected result you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to check if any of the colors in the list are present in the image.

The color bounds in your list seem to be HSV, that is good. 
First convert the input imge to HSV.
Then you can use [inrange](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) to get a mask: a grayscale image where the pixels in the color range are white (value 255) and all others are black (value 0).
Next you can use numpy's [sum](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to sum up all the values.
If the result is larger than 0, there is at least 1 pixel inside the color range.

Here is an example with image displayed for clarity:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# load image
img = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
# Convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of wanted color in HSV 
# you should get these values from the dict  => here I use green
lower_val = np.array([37,42,0]) 
upper_val = np.array([84,255,255]) 

# Threshold the HSV image - any green color will show up as white
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

# if there are any white pixels on mask, sum will be > 0
hasGreen = np.sum(mask)
if hasGreen > 0:
    print('Green detected!')
    print(f'Amount: {hasGreen}')

# display images
cv2.imshow("Input", img)
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

RESULT:

> Green detected!
>   Amount: 1190085

[image]

The example above will return positive when 1 pixel is in range. Depending on your input you may wish to use a threshold. The sum of pixel values can get very large (because each white pixel is 255), dividing by 255 yields the number of pixels in the color range, which may be easier to set a threshold:

```
# set the minimum number of pixel that must be in range
pixelThreshold = 1000
# sum all values of mask, if there are any white pixels on mask, sum will be > 0
hasGreen = np.sum(mask)
# divide by 255 to get the number of white pixels
greenPixels = hasGreen/255
# threshold value
if greenPixels > pixelThreshold:
    print('Green detected!')
    print(f'Number of pixels: {int(greenPixels)}')
```

Result:

> Green detected!
>   Number of pixels: 4667

For ease of use you should put this in a function that you can use when looping over the color list:

```
def hasColor(hsv_img,lower_val,upper_val,pixelThreshold):
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_val, upper_val)
    pixelsFound = np.sum(mask)/255
    if pixelsFound > pixelThreshold:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```